# Accessing <div> from both javascript and code-behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a div with style="display:none". The div should become visible on pressing an html button:

```
function JSAdd() {
    document.getElementById('divDetail').style.display = "block";
}
    <div style="float:left">

    <div id="ctl00_MainContent_upnlLbRD">





            <select size="4" name="ctl00$MainContent$lbRD" id="ctl00_MainContent_lbRD" style="width:188px;">

    <option value="5">one</option>
    <option value="1">two</option>
</select>
```

```
    <input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Добавить" onclick="JSAdd();" />
    <input id="btnEdit" type="button" value="Редактировать" onclick="JSEdit();" />
</div>
<div id="ctl00_MainContent_divDetail" style="display:none" clientidmode="static">
    <div id="ctl00_MainContent_upnlDescription">

            <div>

                <span id="ctl00_MainContent_lblDescription">Описание:</span>

                <input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtDescription" type="text" id="ctl00_MainContent_txtDescription" />  

                <span id="ctl00_MainContent_txtDescriptionRequiredFieldValidator" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">Описание является обязательным для заполнения</span>

            </div>

            <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnSave" value="Сохранить" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainContent$btnSave&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_MainContent_btnSave" />
```

I need to be able to make the div invisible again from code-behind. I cannot access the div unless it is `runat="server"`. But when I add runat="server", the div doesn't become visible on pressing the button from the javascript function above. Could you please help me with this?

Thanks,
David

Comment: Can you paste your html content

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access a div in code-behind by adding the `runat="server"` attribute. Adding this attribute does change the way you access the element in JavaScript though:

```
var el = document.getElementById("<%=div1.ClientID%>");
if (el){
    el.style.display = "none"; //hidden
}
```

There are two ways to adjust the visibility from code-behind, but since you're setting `display:none` in JavaScript, you'd probably want to use the same approach in code-behind:

```
div1.Style["display"] = "block"; //visible
```

In code-behind, you can also set the `Visible` property to false, but this is different because it will prevent the element from being rendered at all.

**EDIT**

If the div is still showing with `display:none` present, you probably have an unclosed tag or quote somewhere affecting the markup. Double check and make sure that the markup is valid.

Comment: Thanks. This works for making div visible, but not to make it invisible again from code-behind. Maybe it is because I am using .Net 3.5?

Comment: No, it still doesn't work from code-behind... BTW, in javascript I set display to block, and in code-behind to none.

Comment: In page source I can see display:none... but the content of the div is still visible. I don't understand it.

Comment: And you're setting display to `none`?: `div1.Style["display"] = "none";`

Comment: Yes, I do. As I said, it is "none" in the page source... And I have no idea why it is still displayed.

Comment: You probably have an unclosed tag or quote somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options, use [`ClientIDMode="Static"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) or use the dynamic `ClientID` at run-time. Both of these options give you server-side access to the object.

**Dynamic:**

```
 <div id="divDetail" runat="server" />
 //or
 <asp:panel id="divDetail" runat="server" />

  function JSAdd() {
    document.getElementById('<%= divDetail.ClientID %>').style.display = "block";
  }

  //to hide from code-beind
  divDetail.Attributes.Add("style","display:none;");
```

**Static(.NET 4.0 +):**

```
 <div id="divDetail" runat="server" ClientIdMode="Static">
  //or
 <asp:panel id="divDetail" runat="server" ClientIdMode="Static" />

  function JSAdd() {
    document.getElementById('divDetail').style.display = "block";
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! For dynamic: This works for making div visible, but not to make it invisible again from code-behind. For static: div doesn't know ClientIdMode, maybe because I use .net 3.5.

Comment: Yes ClientIDMode is .NET 4.0.

Comment: To hide from code behind, divDetail.Attributes.Add("style","display:none");

Comment: I tried it, and in page source I can see display:none... but the content of the div is still visible. I don't understand it.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `Panel`, it renders as a classic `div`

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="divDetail" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Comment: Please be noted that, this is only applicable for ASP.NET 4

Answer (score 2):

When `runat="server"` is applied to an element, asp.net ensures that it has a unique ID by mangling it. Simply ask asp.net for the real client id:

```
function JSAdd() {
    document.getElementById("<%=div1.ClientID%>").style.display = "block";
}
```

Alternatively, you could tell asp.net to leave your ID alone by adding this to your div:

```
<div id="div1" runat="server" clientidmode="Static">
```

**Resources:**

[ClientIdMode="Static" docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! This works for making div visible, but not to make it invisible again from code-behind. And div doesn't know ClientIdMode, maybe because I use .net 3.5.

Comment: @DavidShochet, `ClientIdMode` is .net 40 and up. To hide the div from the server side, use the visible property of the div: `div1.Visible = false;`

Comment: If I do that, I will not be able to make it visible again from javascript, as the invisible div will not exist.

Comment: @DavidShochet, sorry, brain freeze. `div1.Style.Add("display", "none")`

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET, to make IDs unique (if multiple control loaded where same ID are specified), ID on elements are often follow a convention like `ctl00_container1_container2_controlID` and this is what returned when you call `control.ClientID`.

If you consider such a case where there's same ID on the serverside and you loaded those two controls in your page, you may consider using jQuery and life would be easier with `runat="server"` with just matching the ID with the end part:

```
function JSAdd() {
    $("div[id$=divDetails]").show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest technique will be to use Javascript/Jquery to Changes Display property of the Div. if not that you can use following code

```
<form method="post" runat="server">
    <div style = "display:none" id= "div1" runat ="server" >Hello I am visible</div>
    <asp:Button Text="display Div" runat ="server" ID ="btnDisplay" OnClick = "displayDiv" />
    <asp:Button Text="display Div" runat ="server" ID ="btnHideDiv" OnClick = "hideDiv" />
    </form>
```

code behind code is as follows

```
 protected void displayDiv(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        div1.Style.Clear();
        div1.Style.Add("display", "block");
    }
    protected void hideDiv(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        div1.Style.Clear();
        div1.Style.Add("display", "none");
    }
```

guess you Got your solution