# How to hide an element in master page navbar

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to hide menu options from `navbar` in master page based on user roles
but when I tried to call the element it gives me an error.

This is what I did :

MasterPage

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul id="MasterMenu" class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li id="liDashboard">
            <a runat="server" href="~/_Dashboard">Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li id="liTicket">
            <a runat="server" href="~/Forms/Tickets/_Ticket">Ticket+</a>
        </li>
        <li id="liReports">
            <a runat="server" href="-">Reports</a>
        </li>
    </ul>  
</div>
```

And in another page

```
if (User.IsInRole("User"))
{
    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl liDashboard = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("liDashboard");
    liDashboard.Visible = false;
}
```

Also I tried to add `runat="server"` but it still not working.

Comment: Please provide the error you are receiving.

Comment: Error : 

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

liDashboard was null.

Comment: Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416959/c-sharp-error-using-findcontrol-on-div-id. Basically, you need to find your ContentPlaceHolder first and then find your control in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [*Null-Conditional*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) operator (`?.`) and check for null before assignment:

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl liDashboard = 
     (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)Master?.FindControl("liDashboard");
if (liDashboard != null) liDashboard.Visible = false;
```

Also you have missed `runat="server"` in the following line:

```
<li id="liDashboard" runat="server">
```

Comment: The code have no errors but the item still appears in the navbar.

Comment: @MohammadSaffarini Because You have missed `runat="server` for `liDashboard`. Check my updated answer.

Comment: still have the same   here is your update
'                <div id="myDiv" runat="server" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul id="MasterMenu" runat="server" class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li id="liDashboard" runat="server"><a runat="server" href="~/_Dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li id="liTicket"><a runat="server" href="~/Forms/Tickets/_Ticket">Ticket+</a></li>
                        <li id="liReports"><a runat="server" href="-">Reports</a></li>
                    </ul>'

Comment: @MohammadSaffarini Also try to rebuild your project once. It should works fine if you do this steps.

Comment: I test it with response.redirect and it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

For example
if your place holder something like that.

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
```

Try to use something like that

```
Master.FindControl("MainContent").FindControl("liDashboard")
```

Then find your value hierarchically

And of course values need to be with `runat="server"`

**Edit**

Give your `PlaceHolder` an `ID`

`<asp:PlaceHolder ID="Something" runat="server"/>`  and get your value with:

```
Master.FindControl("Something").FindControl("liDashboard")
```

Comment: Still same result

                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl liDashboard =
                     (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)Master?.FindControl("myDiv").
                     FindControl("MasterMenu").FindControl("liDashboard");
                if (liDashboard != null) liDashboard.Visible = false;

Comment: put all master page here and please don't put any (?) null control .You need to get an error if null

Comment: I'll put it as an answer

Comment: check the answer again

Comment: still the same issue

Comment: all of this kind values with runat="server" and after that compile your code?