# How to access htmlcontrol from usercontrol?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a user control which contains unordered list as shown below

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a role="button" data-target="#tree" aria-haspopup="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list">
    </span>Viewer</a></li>
 <li><a role="button" data-target="#tree2" aria-haspopup="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list">
    </span>Sender</a></li>
```

I want to acces these list in the `aspx` page code behind and my purpose is to disable list item `Sender` from unordered lists.How to access and disable it in my code behind?

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/a/46934811/2946329

Comment: but tat is in master page,my question is access li from usercontrol in aspx page

Comment: i got it thanks ,,instead of master i have to use usercontrol id

Comment: where is answer:),yea i vote up the link cheers